# Vertical Sort Order

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, oracle-apex-5.1, fullcalendar-3

Im using the Fullcalendar Control and implemented the `eventOrder` function as described - it works perfect, however it gets only called for events of same length. I would like to know how to customize the Control in order to get the `eventOrder` function called for all events (even events that span across a single day). I have a custom sort attribute pre-calculated.

Im using the Oracle Application Express Framework and the only way I have to put a custom sort attribute is to provide that into a CSS class.

Inside the eventOrder function which I will outline below you see how I have implemented it.

The calendar picture shows exactly where the error is: one event is spanned over 2 days and is not put below the event, in case the event is only for one day, the function gets called and the sort order works. ( I see it in the breakpoint)

Calendar with wrong sort order:

[image]

```
pOptions.eventOrder = function(a, b) {
  var result = 0;
  //if (a.id == '17399' || b.id == '17399') 
  //    alert(a.title + ' vs ' + b.title);
    
  if (parseInt(a.className[0]) > parseInt(b.className[0])) {
    result = 1;
  }
  if (parseInt(a.className[0]) < parseInt(b.className[0])) {
    result = -1;
  }
  return result;
};
```

The version of the FullCalendar seems to be 3.10.0

Comment: Show your implementation please and also mention your version of fullCalendar. Also give examples of the event data and explain your expected result in detail. In other words, provide a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask] for further guidance on how to ask a useful stackoverflow question. Finally, see the [tour] for a general overview of how the site works. Thanks

Comment: Hello, thank you for your Answer - Im using the implementation withing Oracle APEX 5.1 - so I dont have the exact version and the Event Data. (its encapsulated) What I did is added a custom sort function like this into the intialisation code. What it does not is sorting multi-day-spanning events. (its not even called)

Comment: I think the problem is that the algorithm tries to fill gaps and sorts only events properly within the same duration. (one day, two days...)

Comment: At the very least you need to show your fullCalendar code including your eventOrder function, I might be able to guess the version from that. And surely you at least know the title, sort attribute value, and start date and end dates of the problematic events, even if you don't know where to find the JSON data from. Please edit the question with that info, otherwise there's very little anyone can do to help you.

Comment: What are the exact start and end dates/times for the events on each of the days you've circled? As I said before, I can't help you without that information. It's probably worth remembering though that (in v3) [eventOrder](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventOrder) only applies the function in cases where the events have the exact same start and end dates. If that's not the case, it applies its usual rule that events with longer durations and earlier start times are sorted above other events. In v3 you can't override that behaviour - you can only affect what happens if the times are equal.

Comment: OK thank you - this is the solution - I will split the longer events into single ones and I will get my desired result. Thank you!